# List of groups a user is a part of

Tags: linux

In Linux, how do I get a list of all the groups a particular user is a member of?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are the user:

```
groups
```

If he is someone else:

```
groups hisname
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `groups` command, i.e.

```
groups username
```

Answer (score 1):

The `id` [command](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/id/) will list group memberships by both name and id number.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply pilfer through the /etc/group file. It has a simple format:
`groupname: username, username2, username3`, with one group per line.

Or, grep through it.

```
grep '[:,]username' /etc/group
```